# Generalizing the Monotone Subsequence theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, elementary-set-theory

In proving the Bolzaono-Weierstrass theorem, one proves the lemma that every infinite real sequence has a(n infinite) monotone subsequence. In all of the proofs I've seen so far, this is done by constructing the monotone sequence incrementally, either by taking the maximum of a the sequence starting from some point, or (if the maximum does not exist) by taking increasingly large values.
This made me curious about a more genral hypothesis, that cannot be proved using the same method:

**Hypothesis**: Given linearily ordered sets, $I$ and $A$, such that $|I|\ge\aleph_0$, and a family $\{a_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}\in A^I$, then there exists a subset $J\subseteq I$, $|J|=|I|$, such that $\{a_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in J}$ is monotone, i.e. for all $\beta,\gamma\in J$, either $a_\beta \le a_\gamma$ whenever $\beta\lt\gamma$, or $a_\beta \ge a_\gamma$ whenever $\beta\lt\gamma$.

Any ideas on how can I go about proving, or disproving, this hypothesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in general false. For instance, let $\mathfrak c=|\mathbb R|$, thought of as an ordinal. Let $I=\mathfrak c$, $A=\mathbb R$, and $(a_\alpha\mid \alpha<\mathfrak c)$ a well-ordering of $\mathbb R$. The point is that $\mathbb R$ has no monotone sequences of length $\omega_1\le\mathfrak c$.

The same holds for any $\kappa$ in place of $\aleph_0$: The set ${}^\kappa 2$ of functions from $\kappa$ to $\{0,1\}$ is linearly ordered lexicographically, and contains no monotone subsequences of length $\kappa^+\le 2^\kappa$.

(What we see here is a failure of certain partition relations. This has been studied extensively by Erdős and his collaborators.)

The result holds for some sizes under appropriate large cardinal assumptions (such as measurability of $|I|$, though less is needed).

Comment: There are also many particular examples of pairs of ordered sets where the statement holds, and it may be interesting to collect some such instances.